# Airflow DAG exists in dag_list, but cannot be triggered and does not show up in UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-webserver

I have the directory for my dag in the airflow/dags directory, and when calling `airflow dags list` while logged into the webserver, the dag's ID shows up in the list. However, calling `airflow dags list` while logged into the scheduler returns the following error:

```
Killed
command terminated with exit code 137
```

The dag also does not show up in list on the webserver UI. When manually entering the dag_id in the url, it shows up with every task in the right place, but triggering a manual run via the `Trigger DAG` button results in a pop_up stating `Cannot find dag <dag_id>`. Has anyone run into this issue before? Is this a memory problem?

My DAG code is written in python, and the resulting DAG object has a large number of tasks (>80).
Running on airflow 1.10.15 with a kubernetes executor